# How to prevent a battery powered microcontroller(ESP32) from reseting when motors start running?

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, lipo, esp32, quad-copter

I am working on a brushed motor quadcopter. It is powered by a 3.7V LiPo Battery. I have an ESP32 microcontroller which sends PPM signal to a SP Racing F3 EVO Brushed flight controller. The 3.3V to the ESP32 are provided by a LDO regulator(MCP-1700-330) and the flight controller board is powered directly by the same battery. The issue I am facing is that when the brushed coreless motors start running the ESP32 resets(via Brownout Detection). I read similar threads which suggested using large valued capacitors at the regulator input/output else using separate power supplies. In my case I did try large capacitors(470uF) at the input of the regulator but the ESP32 still reseted. And it is not possible for me to use a separate power supply. Please help me as to how I may solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You must make sure that the motors do not drain your capacitor. Try adding a (Schottky) diode before the LDO and put the capacitor after the diode and before the LDO:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5VQ1V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried a Schottky diode (BAT85) and a cap(470u) in the configuration you suggested. Now no reset occurs when the motors spin till 50% duty cycle(PWM) but beyond it the controller resets. What may I do? Will increasing capacitance work?

Comment: You could try but you might have an inherent power problem. Meaning there may be no simple solution.